# In Oracle SQL: How do you insert the current date + time into a table?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, sql-insert

I've written below code, but it only seems to insert the current date and not the current time. Anyone knows how to do that?

```
insert into errortable
(dateupdated,table1id)
values
(TO_DATE(sysdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),1083);
```

Comment: How do you know that its only inserting current date?Did you try it by looking at the raw table or have you tried viewing it using a query?

Comment: yeah it stores 00:00 as time ; i confirmed by looking in table. want to store current date and current time

Comment: Clue : In Oracle, Current Date + Time = Sysdate. `select sysdate from dual would produce 2015-10-05 09:24:40`.

Comment: `TO_DATE(sysdate...)` is just wrong. `sysdate` returns a `date` - never ever call `TO_DATE` with a date because it will usually not give the results you might expect, and doesn't make sense anyway.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It only seems to because that is what it is printing out.  But actually, you shouldn't write the logic this way.  This is equivalent:

```
insert into errortable (dateupdated, table1id)
    values (sysdate, 1083);
```

It seems silly to convert the system date to a string just to convert it back to a date.

If you want to see the full date, then you can do:

```
select TO_CHAR(dateupdated, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), table1id
from errortable;
```

Comment: thanks @gordon . are you saying sysdate insert should store the current date and current time using your method ?

Comment: @Tikkaty . . . Yes, `sysdate` has a time component.

Answer (score -2):

You may try with below query :

```
INSERT INTO errortable (dateupdated,table1id)
VALUES (to_date(to_char(sysdate,'dd/mon/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ),1083 );
```

To view the result of it:

```
SELECT to_char(hire_dateupdated, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
FROM errortable 
    WHERE table1id = 1083;
```

Comment: it does not make sense to convert sysdate to a string and then back to a date