# How can I replace date in oracle systimestamp

Tags: oracle, timestamp, systimestamp

I can only use specific basedate value(YYYYMMDD) at my query.

I'd like to insert data with timestamp but just replaced with that date

```
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, regTs)
 VALUES (:field1, :field2, systimestamp);
```

from this query, how can I apply :basedate + systimestamp's hour, minute, second, microsecond

Comment: seems duplicate. see the answer `[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32939206/in-oracle-sql-how-do-you-insert-the-current-date-time-into-a-table)1

Comment: Please add some sample date values that the application will insert and what you want to have inserted into the table. For example, if the application inserts 20170708, what would you want to see if it were queried with select * from table?

Comment: @jeff6times7 if today is 20170710 and current time is 18:46:14.2341 and :basedate is 20160502 then inserted data would be 2016-05-02 18:46:14.2341
I wanna use :basedate and current systimestamp time. The answer bellow is what I wanted. But I wanna find better way

Comment: @abend0 Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First convert date to string using To_Char and concatenate time string with date string, now you can use To_Date function to convert the datetime string into timestamp.

Ex:

```
to_date(to_char(BASEDATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD') || ' ' ||TO_CHAR(sysdate,'HH24:MI:SS.FF'), 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thx. But I'm worry about speed with this solution. thousands of transaction processed in few minute. Is this is the only way?

Comment: @abend0 Try to do the concatenation in the scripting side if possible.  
And read the following article
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2014/14-sep/o54asktom-2279184.html

Answer (score 0):

If you know :basedate is constant for a given user experience (execution of a task), then your first step should be to calculate the interval between sysdate and :basedate. Execute this once to figure it out and minimize CPU consumption later:

```
select numtodsinterval(sysdate - :basedate, 'DAY') dsinterval
from dual;
```

Then you can replace `systimestamp` in your insert statement text with this:

```
systimestamp - :dsinterval
```

If :basedate changes quite frequently, then you have to put more of the code into the expression, like this:

```
systimestamp - numtodsinterval(sysdate - :basedate, 'DAY')
```

Obviously, in the above examples, the datatype for :basedate is date. If it were a string datatype, then you would have to refer to it like this if the date string is formatted according to the current setting of NLS_DATE_FORMAT:

```
to_date(:basedate)
```

or this depending upon how the date string were formatted:

```
to_date(:basedate, 'some date format string')
```